# Получить список процессов по имени пользователя

Tags: python, процесс, wmi

Необходимо получить список процессов конкретного пользователя на удаленной машине

```
    import wmi
    c = wmi.WMI(hostname, user='user', pass='pass')
    for process in c(): #for procees in c(name='notepad.exe')
        print(process.Name)
```

name='notepad.exe' - позволяет отсортировать процессы по имени,
а есть ли возможность фильтрации по имени пользователя?